# How to separate data from column A & present it in good form in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have data in COLUMN A. Is there any formula so I can separate the data & make it look it it's in COLUMN B? I want to make data from Column A to look like it's in B

[image]

What formula can I use to separate that time and present in the form of Column B?

Comment: Is there always " - " and ", " as the separators?

Comment: Yes there's always